# Short-cut for selecting excel ready-made cell formatting. NOT formatting to table.

Tags: excel

I have previously known an excel short-cut command that popped up an window where one could select a layout for a range of cells in the worksheet. There were many selections and several of them were quite beautiful. The layout would change the background color of the heading (first row selected), and format the first column and the cells in the body respectively.

I'm not talking about making tables or the table formatter, also it was only accessible through the shortcut command as far as I know (which I've now forgotten). Does anyone recall what I mean and could that person please share? I've been trying to remember it for some time now.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I believe what you first need to do is enable Excel to recognise your table. Take a look at my screenshot above!

Comment: Nope, that is not it. It is a seperate window that pops up with ready-made suggestions of cell range formatting. It is a stand-alone window just as if you press Ctrl + 1 for cell formatting. But with lists of different themes you can apply to your cell range.

Comment: I'm not aware of any shortcuts that cannot be reached using the ribbon?

Comment: There are several I believe. How about Alt + E + L ( delete current worksheet ).

Comment: Can be accessed via "Home -> Cells -> Delete -> Delete Sheet"

Answer (score 0):

By using Alt + O + A one will get up the AutoFormat window.